# Background image on mobile stretched or not showing

Tags: css, image, mobile, background-image

Hi people, 
I truly do not know what to do anymore.  I have read through the topics and tried almost everything I thought it would work but nothing!

So here it goes: My background image shows and resizes normal with the desktop browser BUT on my mobile (in this case iPhone 6S) it is stretched (looks kind of blurry) or it doesn’t show at all.

Link to my page (http://lauramaliqi.com/about.html )

MY CODE  ( I added the H1 and p - just in case if they are affecting the upper code. This code is used also for all the other pages, that also give the same result as this one. )

```
.top-bar-about { 
 color: #333;
 height: 350px;
 padding: 100px 0 10px;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient( rgba(255, 255, 255, .8), rgba(255, 255, 255, .8)), url(../img/laura_background1.jpg);
background: linear-gradient( rgba(255, 255, 255, .8), rgba(255, 255, 255, .8)), url(../img/laura_background.jpg);
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center center;
text-align: center;}

.top-bar-about h1 { 
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #999;
    line-height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;}

.top-bar-about p { 
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #999;
    line-height: 10px;
    font-family:'Walter Turncoat', sans-serif;}
```

I have tried changing background-attachment: fixed to scroll; changed the background image size ‘cause I read on one of the posts that could also be the issue. Played with the @media queries - no result. Put down no repeat then it messes with my desktop image..basically whatever I tried It just DOES NOT work.

Just to add I know sometimes cache can be a bug in the browser but I delete cache all the time when I upload new files but on the phone..that damn pic just does not react. Its like its frozen.

Thank you in advance!!

p.s. I also did some screenshots just in case

**How it should be**

[image: How it should be]

**How it is at the moment**

[image: How it is at the moment]

Comment: Can you start a fiddle, your link is working fine on mobile chrome browser and firefox. It is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Just checked on my iOS 10 device and figured out that this happens because of

```
 background-attachment: fixed;
```

Try once again and change the value from 'fixed' to 'scroll' for mobile devices:

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {

 .top-bar-about{
    background-attachment: scroll;
    padding: 254px 0px !important;
 }

}
```

And make sure that styles aren't cached and do not override each other.

[With background-attachment: fixed;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r50kj.jpg)

[Width background-attachment: scroll;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Rody.jpg)